# Is there a Virtual Key Code for '

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

Does the ' (Apostrophe) key have a VK code? I cannot find it online for the life of me. I came by VK_OEM_7, however that is giving me errors in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VK_QUOTE was what I was looking for.